# In Oracle Sql in ubuntu How Can I open editor to write PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Unlike windows writing the command

`ED "name.sql"`

editor is not opened here.

Like in windows writing the command `ED "name.sql"`, notepad opens.
How can I do it in Ubuntu?I have installed SQL* plus in ubuntu.

Comment: you mean something like this ? cat /home/ora/randomtext.txt

Comment: Install sql developer for Ubuntu : https://askubuntu.com/questions/458554/how-to-install-sql-developer-on-ubuntu-14-04 or SQL*  plus https://askubuntu.com/questions/159939/how-to-install-sqlplus?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Like in windows writing the command ED "name.sql" notepad opens how can I do it in Ubuntu?I have installed SQL plus in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have a `vim/vi` editor in ubuntu. Enter the below line in your SQL* plus session.

```
define _editor='vim'
```

Now, when you do

```
ED name.sql
```

It will launch the `vim` editor.

To save the editor settings permanently,  edit the file `$ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql` and add the line

```
define _editor='vim'
```

Comment: The first command is working, It's showing I can't change the permissions as I am not the owner.

Comment: @sujoy : I won't be able to assist for access / permission related issues. It works perfectly from my redhat account. You have to check with how to give proper directory / file permissions or get it from some other Ubuntu admin user. You may accept the answer if you wish so that it might help others..